# How to execute independent function after write to bigquery in dataflow batch pipeline using python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to move file to different bucket after its successfully loaded to bigquery, but the independent function is executing before pipeline starts how to time the execution of independent function '**process()**' to run after successfully loading to bigquery.

```
def process(file_name):
    """Moves a blob from one bucket to another."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    source_bucket=storage_client.bucket('source_bucket')
    destination_bucket=storage_client.bucket('destination bucket')
    source_blob=source_bucket.blob(file_name)
    destination_blob_name=(file_name)
    blob_copy = source_bucket.copy_blob(source_blob, destination_bucket,destination_blob_name)
    source_bucket.delete_blob(file_name)
    print('File {} is transfered from {} to{}'.format(file_name,source_bucket,destination_bucket))

def run(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args, save_main_session=True)
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        from google.cloud import storage
        client = storage.Client()
        bucket = client.bucket('sourcebucket')
        blob = bucket.get_blob('sourcefile.avro')
        downloaded_blob = "temporary.avro"
        blob.download_to_filename(downloaded_blob)
        reader = DataFileReader(open(downloaded_blob, "rb"), DatumReader())
        file_name=blob.name
        records = [r for r in reader]
        # Populate pandas.DataFrame with records
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
        
        (
        convert.to_pcollection(df,pipeline=p,label="pcollection ")
        |'To dictionaries ' >> beam.Map(lambda x: dict(x._asdict()))
        | 'WriteToBigQuery ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery('projectID:datasetID.table',
          schema='SCHEMA_AUTODETECT',
          create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
          write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,)
        
        |'move'>>beam.FlatMap(process(file_name)
        )
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not from a python background, but I have implemented something similar in Java.
The way you would want to approach this is to use `FileReader.match()` that would return you Metadata of the new files.
Then you would bifurcate this collection into two, one (PCollection1) would get the metadata and do `FileIO.readMatches or TextIO.read()` and then further process this data and write it to a sink.

In another branch you would use `Wait.on(PCollection1).apply(ParDo.of(new yourDeleteFn))` and then inside a ParDo create a storage client and move those files that have already been processed into another bucket.